# Hadoop version layout error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting this error in one or two nodes in a Hadoop cluster, where rest of the nodes are running fine:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException:  
*********** Upgrade is not supported from this older version of storage to 
the current version. Please upgrade to Hadoop-0.14 or a later version and 
then upgrade to current version. Old layout version is 'too old' and latest 
layout version this software version can upgrade from is -7.
```

Any idea how to fix this problem, without losing the data?

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question unless we also know what version of Hadoop you encountered this on, and what you were running previously.